# Solving $xy'=x^2 + 3y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reviewing for my Calculus II final and I've stumbled upon a differential that I'm stuck on.

> Solve the differential equation: $$xy'=x^2 + 3y, \quad x>0$$

I've tried dividing both sides by the x on the left but then the 3y/x gets you stuck, I've tried subtracting the 3y but I got stuck there as well. Any insight is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So you wish to solve the differential equation? If you know the method of integrating factors, this is fast.

Comment: The equation is $y' - \frac{3}{x}y = x$. Integrating factor! $e^{-\int f(x){\rm d}x}\frac{d}{dx}[y(x)e^{\int f(x){\rm d}x}]= y' + f(x) y$

Comment: Can you solve the homogeneous equation $x y' = 3y$?  And then perhaps finish by variation of parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I forgot about integrating factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is :

$$xy' = x^2 + 3y \Leftrightarrow y' - \frac{3y}{x} = x$$

Let $\mu(x) = e^{\int -3/x\mathrm{d}x} = 1/x^3$ be an integrating factor and multiply both sides of the equation by it :

$$\frac{y'}{x^3} - \frac{3y}{x^4}=\frac{1}{x^2} \Leftrightarrow \bigg(\frac{y}{x^3}\bigg)' = \frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\int \bigg(\frac{y}{x^3}\bigg)'\mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x $$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{y}{x^3} = -\frac{1}{x} + c_1 \Leftrightarrow \boxed{y(x) = x^2(c_1x-1)}$$

You can also solve it by transforming it to an exact equation but this is very longer and not needed in such a simple scenario.

Comment: Got it, didn't know I was supposed to use integrating factor for this one. Thanks. Ill get back to reviewing.

Comment: @LukeD Standard trick. "Supposed to" is not such a good phrase in maths, as things have many solutions most of the times. But yes, it's a fast and easy way out in this case!

Comment: I was confused because I was looking in the wrong spot. I thought it was a separable but I understand now.

Comment: Glad I could help !

Answer (score 2):

By adding $2x^2$ to both sides we obtain$$xy'+2x^2=3y+3x^2$$therefore $$x(y'+2x)=3(y+x^2)$$which means that $$y+x^2=Cx^3$$or $$y=Cx^3-x^2$$for $C>0$

Comment: That's a clever answer! It may be useful to make explicit the logarithm in the integration step since it's not as straightforward as the other ones.